# Navbar active tab change color when scrolled

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, background-color

I would like my active tab to *change* colour when user scroll pass 1000px and *return* to original color when it's <1000px.

I've tried the CSS below which works and changes the background on active tab *permanently*.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active{
   background: #111;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background: #111;
}
```

Also tried combining the CSS above and a scroll function, but I don't think I'm targeting the active div right... **How can I best target this active tab class in a scroll function?** Or is there a better alternative to this method?

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lczsjz3y/7/

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

From your fiddle, it looks like you just need to add a listener to the scroll event, because as you have it now, it just pulls the `scrollTop()` value on load.  So, something similar to this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (scroll > 1000) {
     // change class
     $(this).find("navbar .active").css({
       "backgroundColor":"#000"
      });
   } else {
     // change it back
     $(this).find("navbar.active").css({
        "backgroundColor":"gray"
     });
   }
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do understand what you're saying, and it makes sense. However, i'm still struggling with .find("this part") of the code. Would you be able to run it on a JsFiddle when you have a minute?

Comment: did the active tab change color when scroll > 1000 on your end?

Comment: Is it not working on your page or just not working in jsfiddle?  Thanks.

Comment: not working on my page. Well I guess it's alright not having this function. Though it would be cool and I'm really curious about it but thanks for your time Lucas! :) really appreciate it!

Comment: something just clicked and I try to play with what I know (going around it). Now it works the way I wanted https://jsfiddle.net/y791ur1x/3/ I wanted to change the "active" tab bg-color only because I've change my "navbar" bg-color. Thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {  
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 1000) {
        $(".navbar").css({"background-Color": "black"});
    } else {
        $(".navbar").css({"background-Color": "yellow"});
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lczsjz3y/21/

Comment: thanks for your input:) That does works for the navbar bg-color but...I was more aiming for the active tab.

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect and not the best solution, but I've tried playing around with what I know and manage to get what I wanted. https://jsfiddle.net/y791ur1x/3/

```
$(document).scroll(function () {

 var y = $(this).scrollTop();

 if (y >= 1100) {
  $('.navbar').removeClass("navbar-inverse").addClass("navbar-default");
  $(".navbar-custom").css({
    "backgroundColor":"#000000"
  });
 } else {
  $('.navbar').removeClass("navbar-default").addClass("navbar-inverse");
  $(".navbar-custom").css({
    "backgroundColor":"#222222"
  });
 }
});
```

Still look forward to a proper clean solution though!! ^^