# HTML Navigation bar multiple background color for each section title

Tags: html, css, navbar

Html div:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="hidden">
      <a href="#page-top"></a>
    </li>
    <li> 
      <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Css code:

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav>.active>a {
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#fed136
}
```

Hello, I have this navigation bar, when you scroll down to each section of the website, the name of the section from the tob bar (the active one) will take a background color (#fed136).
I am trying to do something but it didn't work: when scrolling down, I want each section to have a specific color, so I don't want that one background color to be as default.
I tried to add and "id" to each section, it didn't work.

```
<a class="page-scroll" href="#services" id="serv_id">Services</a>
#serv_id.navbar-custom .navbar-nav>.active>a {background-color:red !important}
```

**This is an example of what I am trying to do** : http://www.rad-road.com/Capture.PNG http://www.rad-road.com/Capture2.PNG
Any help?

Comment: Try solution from that stack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675604/changing-background-color-of-div-on-scroll

Comment: Modify only part to change color

Comment: Look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728029/navbar-active-tab-change-color-when-scrolled?rq=1

Comment: Thank you I checked this, the problem isn't by changing the section background, the problem is by changing to background color of the top bar (navbar) titles color. I hope you understand.

Comment: I uploaded example to check :  http://www.rad-road.com/Capture.PNG http://www.rad-road.com/Capture2.PNG

Answer (score 0):

When you use an ID, that's all you need to specify in your CSS. An ID must be unique on the page. When the classes are removed, it works fine.

```css
#serv_id {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="page-scroll" href="#services" id="serv_id">Services</a>
```

Comment: Yes it works but permanent, I want it to work only when the section is active, I mean only when I scroll down to this section. I tried  `#serv_id>.active a {background-color: red;}` didn't work